# probability statistics

Tags: probability, statistics

If there was a tree randomly distributed in a degraded forest at a rate of $5 \text{ trees}/ 1000 m^2$ (meter squared), then what is the probability of finding one or more of these trees in a randomly selected $100 m^2$ plot ??

I have no idea where to start from, can any one help and explain please.

Comment: Probably it is intended that the number of trees in that random plot has a Poisson distribution, so you're looking for the probability that a Poisson-distributed random variable is at least $1$.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a **Poisson distributed** random variable with a mean of **5/1000**.

P(equal to or more than 1 trees in 100 m^2 ) = 
1- P(0 trees) =

1 - (5 x 100/1000)^0 x e^(-5 x 100/1000)/0! = 0.3935

Answer (score 2):

As Michael Hardy said, this is most naturally modeled with a Poisson distribution.

You are told that the rate is 5 per 1000 m2 and asked to find the probability of finding a tree in 100 m2. You need to scale the rate to 0.5 per 100 m2 and then the probability will be 1-Poisson($0;\lambda=0.5$).

Comment: so after we change the λ to 0.5 we have to find pr(y=0) and then the answer should be the sum of the 1-pr(y=0), which is 0.3939           isn't that right ?

Comment: @kingjames yes that is right.